# How to center a part of a sentence?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
summed over all particles \centerline{$\qquad \ddtt\sum_j
m_i\br_i=\sum_i \bF_i+\sum_{\substack {i,j \\ i\neq j}} \bF_{ij}$}
```

[image]

So how to make the second formula centered relative to the whole line rather than to the rest of the line?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! If only we knew what the `\ddtt` command is…

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! In a normal setup the font size is too large for that text+formula to have place on a single line. Please provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @Bernard - I think `\ddtt` generates `\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{dt}^2}`... :-)

Comment: Why are you using `\centerline` in the first place and not `\[ .... \]` (no `$`'s) as normal for a line of displayed math.

Comment: @Bernard Sorry I didn't make that clear. It generates `\dfrac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dt^2}`.

Comment: @daleif I want to make the text and the formula in the same line, while only the formula is centered. Any idea how to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (the horizontal line is there just to indicate the width of the text block)?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\newcommand\ddtt{\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{dt}^2}}
\newcommand\bF{\bm{F}}
\newcommand\br{\bm{r}}
\begin{document}
\hrule\bigskip
\[
\text{summed over all particles}\quad 
\ddtt\sum_j m_i \br_i
= \sum_i \bF_i+\sum_{\substack {i,j \\ i\neq j}} \bF_{ij}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks! but actually I want what Bernard offered.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two possibilities: one with the formula centred in the page,  and another with the formula centred w.r.t. the remaining space on the line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{esdiff, bm}
\usepackage{linegoal} 

\begin{document}

\noindent \rlap{summed over all particles} \centerline{$\qquad \diff[2]{}{t}\sum_j
m_i\bm{r}_i=\sum_i \bm{F}_i+\sum_{\substack {i,j \\ i\neq j}} \bm{F}_{ij}$}\bigskip

\noindent summed over all particles\makebox[\linegoal]{$\qquad \diff[2]{}{t}\sum_j
m_i\bm{r}_i=\sum_i \bm{F}_i+\sum_{\substack {i,j \\ i\neq j}} \bm{F}_{ij}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The first one is what I want. And the esdiff package which I didn't know is also a great help.o